# LINQ group by property as a parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects that I want to query using LINQ. I want to be able to group them by a property.

```
var query = from item in expense
    orderby item.ExpenseTime descending
    group item by item.Location;

var query = from item in expense
    orderby item.ExpenseTime descending
    group item by item.ExpenseType;

var query = from item in expense
    orderby item.ExpenseTime descending
    group item by item.Person;
```

Is there a way to specify the property as an argument of a method?

```
public static void GetExpensesBy(List<Expense> expense, Property myGroupingProperty)
{
    var query = from item in expense
                orderby item.ExpenseTime descending
                group item by item.myGroupingProperty;

    // ....
}
```

Note that after the query there is code that is generic and does not care about the group.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you modify your `GetExpenseBy` as below

```
public static void GetExpensesBy<TKey>(List<Expense> expense, 
                                       Func<Expense, TKey> myGroupingProperty)
{
    var query = (from item in expense
                 orderby item.ExpenseTime descending
                 select item).GroupBy(myGroupingProperty);
    // ....
}
```

Then you can call this function as

```
GetExpensesBy(expense, item => item.Location);
GetExpensesBy(expense, item => item.Person);
GetExpensesBy(expense, item => item.ExpenseType);
```

Comment: Could i make a multi GroupBy in the same expression? example: group by location, then person in the same expression? like  GetExpensesBy(expense, item => item.Location, item => item.Person);

Comment: If you need to groupby both person and location you can use `GetExpensesBy(expense, item => new { item.Location, item.Person});`

Comment: how convert it to Dictionary<TKey, List<Expense>>

Comment: What is the TKey going to contain?

Comment: How do you get the newly created collection from the function as the function is a void that returns nothing?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff - I used void as the OP had it void in their question.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft wrote a Dynamic Linq library.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx

This lib will allow you to specify any of the Linq query dyanamically

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void GetExpensesBy<T>(List<Expense> expense, Expression<Func<A,T>> groupbyExpression)
{
    var query = from item in expense
                orderby item.ExpenseTime descending;
    query.GroupBy(groupbyExpression);

    // ....
}
```

and create the expression like;

```
Expression<Func<Expense, string>> group = (q) => q.Location;
```

Comment: why you want to use Expression<Func<>>?